# How to get data and write to file?

Tags: php, xml, file, do-loops

I want to get `blog01.xml` from `data01.xml`, `blog02.xml` from `data02.xml` and so on. I'm trying with the following code, but it doesn't work. What is wrong?

```
<?php
$v = 1;
do {

    $file = "RAW/" . 'data[$v].xml';
    $postxml = @file_get_contents($file);

    $postxml = str_replace("-", " ", $postxml);

    file_put_contents("XML/" . 'blog0[$v].xml', $postxml);
    $v++;
} while($v<=5);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
file_put_contents('XML/blog0'.$v.'.xml', $postxml);
```

Comment: Thanks Raghav Sood, that's more convinient. Have a nice day